# why os.path.normpath does not remove the firsts //?

Tags: python, os.path

Why the first `//` are not removed ?

The following code:

```
import os
os.path.normpath('//var//lib/')
```

returns

```
'//var/lib'
```

not

```
'/var/lib'
```

Here the definition:

```
normpath(path)
    '''Normalize path, eliminating double slashes, etc.'''
```

Comment: does `'//var/lib'` not work?

Comment: Its returning `\\var\\lib`

Comment: @SuperStew yes it works but it does not match my unittests according to definition.

Comment: @BlackThunder: "On Windows, it also converts forward slashes to backward slashes."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because on Windows, there is a path ambiguity that python preserves.

`//var/whatever` could refer to a drive mounted as the name `//var`

OR

`/var/whatever` could refer to a local drive directory.

If python collapsed leading double slashes, you could unknowingly change a path to refer to a different location.

Another way of saying this is that `//var` and `/var` are fundamentally different paths, and python treats them differently. You should probably change your test case to reflect this.

Comment: `//var` is only well-defined to be a remote filesystem reference on Windows, *but* `//foo` is allowed to be given local/special handling on UNIX too (see last sentence of the spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11). It *isn't* given that handling on most out-of-the-box UNIX systems, but filesystems like AFS where it's special do exist.

Comment: Didn't know that! OP seems to be on windows, but that's an important edge case.